# Got a Linq Nested Query Error - Any Workarounds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a string that I convert into a 2 dimensional array for a Linq lookup.

```
var searchWords = "one two three | four five six";

var groups = searchWords.Split('|')
    .Select(x => x.Split())
    .ToArray();
```

I'm then querying one of my Entity Framework tables - the idea being that I'm searching for rows that match all three words (in any order) in at least one group.

So `"three one two"` is a valid result.

I'm using a generic unit of work/repository pattern (just in case anyone's confused) but it accepts any expression just like a Where clause.

Here's the query that's failing:

```
var result = Base.View.Query<Keyword>(k =>
    groups.Any(g => g.All(w => k.Term.Contains(w))));

The table Keyword contains a string name 'Term'.
The content of Term would be something like "three two one".
```

As you can see, I'm trying to find `.Any() group` where `.All() the words` are `contained in the table string k.Term`

The query above is the equivalent of this next query, which works:

```
var result = Base.View.Query<Keyword>(k =>
    primaryGroup.All(w => k.Term.Contains(w)) ||
    secondaryGroup.All(w => k.Term.Contains(w)))
```

But unfortunately, this one isn't easily scalable.

I'm getting the dreaded can't accept this nested query error.

```
The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'
```

I'm not looking for a hack for the nesting problem, but wondered if there was another way of restructuring the Linq query so it does the same thing in a different way

Comment: what should be the output

Comment: @KunalMukherjee result is IEnumerable<Keyword>

Comment: No I mean how do you want to split/group it

Comment: The first split, splits the string on the |, then the second split, splits the words on space - so the example at the start of this post would result in 2 groups containing 3 words, which creates a 2D array. The split is done outside of the query (the group variable) because Linq to Entities does not support .Split(). As for the query, I just want to return matching rows.

Comment: @JohnOhara what kind of error you actually get?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan - it's this one, quite common if you Google it. The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'

Comment: The approach is to use something like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to scale your second query to all the members of `groups`, replacing the `Any`.